# Can * (asterisk) be passed to python as literal character

Tags: python, bash, arguments

I am making a python script which should take a variable amount of inputs. I have stumbled upon a little problem. I want to pass an asterisk (*) the python script as `python script.py asdf * 432 foo`

If we do this the script will get all files and folders passed instead of the asterisk. Is this possible without escaping the asterisk?

Comment: You can disable globbing with `set -f`, but that's more trouble than just escaping the `*`.

Comment: Also, this has nothing to do with Python; it's purely a shell question, and specific to shells that treat `*` as a pattern to expand.

Comment: No easi way then. But it makes sense, though it would be nice if the recieving program could choose how to interpret the arguments

Comment: @chepner - well it would be if python had a way to circumvent or choose how to interpret the asterisk ^_^ But thanks for clarifying!

Comment: That would require communication between Python and whatever program is executing it using a standard protocol; that's far more complicated than simply knowing how to use your particular shell to specify the values you actually want.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to escape it.

```
python script.py asdf \* 432 foo
```

Comment: The problem states "Is this possible without escaping the asterisk?" So the answer is no or as stated by @chepner to `set -f`.

Comment: Oh I missed that, my bad. Are you going to post the answer yourself or do you want me to edit my post?

Comment: If you could edit your post and maybe flag to close the question, as it already has been marked with a solution elsewhere.